# Why arithmetic operation return NaN in this case?

Tags: javascript, dom

With a practice in JS i making some very simple app, which counts how much you have to pay as a tip in cafe. While i was making a formula, wich counts exactly the tips i struggled with problem, which i cannot explain. If i trying to count all in one formula i have a NaN as a result, but if i make a couple new variables i have a result whicn i expecting. Here is a code:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  const bill = document.getElementById('bill');
  const company = document.getElementById('people');
  const radioButtons = document.getElementsByName('service');
  const calcButton = document.getElementById('calculator');
  const resultDiv = document.getElementById('result-div');

  function calcTips() {
    let result;
    let srv;
    let billValue = parseFloat(bill.value);
    let comValue = parseFloat(company.value);
    for(let i = 0; i < radioButtons.length; i++) {
      if(radioButtons[i].checked === true) {
        switch(i) {
          case 0:
            svr = 30;
            break;
          case 1:
            svr = 20;
            break;
          case 2:
            svr = 15;
            break;
          case 3:
            svr = 10;
            break;
          case 4:
            svr = 0;
            break;
        }
      }
    }
    // arithmetic operations
    let temp = billValue / 100 * svr;
    let temp2 = billValue + temp;
    result = temp2 / comValue;
    console.log(result);
  }

  calcButton.addEventListener('click', calcTips);
}
```

that code i running good, but if i make one formula:

```
result = (billValue + (billValue / 100 * svr)) / comValue;
```

it returns NaN, can you explain me why?

Comment: @lokesh because the OP didn't include the html, doesjt matter for the question...

Comment: I guess you are getting `0/0` in some of your calculation. Can you include some input which throws that error

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. The code you say "is running good" actually throws an exception. Did you test it? Are you 100% sure that your code is a [mcve]? In particular, it looks like it is neither minimal (are you absolutely sure that it is 100% impossible to demonstrate the problem in less than 39 lines) nor complete (did you test and verify that the code works *exactly* as you posted it and there is nothing missing from it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you declare :

```
let srv;
```

but use like this :

```
let temp = billValue / 100 * svr;
                              ^-------------
```

For Fix change like :

Change `let srv;` to `let svr;`

Comment: turned out it's typo error

Comment: OP has used `svr` in lot of places, I think it's better to change this `let srv;` to `let svr;`

Answer (score 0):

the NAN mean that the value is not a number 
because some of variable in the equation is not a number 
you does not assign any number value to svr so the default value is null and this lead to NaN in the equation